# How to host multiple HTML 5 games from a database?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, html5-canvas

I am building a game website with game upload functionality. I am working with React and .NET Core API. The users can upload a zip file encapsulating their HTML5 game.

I was wondering what is the best approach to serve this uploaded game on React?

Currently, on the request of a game I take the zip file by game ID, unzip it and construct a collection of FileStreamResult. I was planning to serve the entire game on a backend endpoint and just wrap the reference to an iframe back on React. However, I could not figure out how to return a View using the filestreams.

Comment: This is a demo project. It will not be exposed to the internet. If I want to later expose, I could implement extra middleware for upload to prevent misuse.

Comment: IMO this use case doesn't even have anything to do with React. You can just use plain JS or jQuery to solve this.

Comment: The solution to this problem is applicable to all use cases. Only way to serve React is a backend endpoint but using plain JS, we might also have the option of receiving the game statically and load statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by using a composite key for additional files and rendering the index.html page as a razor page from file. The rendered page asks for resources which I have an endpoint logic for finding the required files.

Answer (score 0):

first of all please don't store .zips or any other huge files as Base64 in a database. Let the users upload the file directly to the server (or an additional server resource) including max. file size and a virus check (see [ClamAV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nClam)). You can however for sure store the path to the folder in your database.

I'd then unzip the game by code automatically (or after revision) on the server. Afterwards you can simply render the games index.html file (or render that content in your wrapper page using razor).

However, you should make sure that users are not uploading weird stuff.

Comment: I am not storing any zips. I am unzipping the files upon receiving and updating the database.

Comment: Does the games content get stored in the db in any way? If not - that's great :)

Comment: I store the game files to the db with a composite key => gameId and path. I already have logic for size but I did not think of a virus check. I think in the end I can manually check submissions and publish only the clean stuff.

Comment: No matter how much automation I plant along the way, I do not think it can ensure complete safety.

Comment: True but you can start and make sure that the content does not contain an executable file. However as long as you can render the games index.html you have a great start! Good luck :)

Comment: Yes I will have an accepted mimes logic thank you :)